# how to read data from one db table and write data to another table using spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am learning spring batch for my new project so I have given a new task which is extracting sum of a all row data from "a" table in A database to "b" table in A database.

I googled but I found examples only for xml to database and xml to database but not from db table to another table.

Please provide me some examples for the above scenario.

Thank you.

Comment: Still unanswered after 6 years?  Here's a very simple example from where to start: https://github.com/youtix/spring-batch-database-to-database/tree/master/src/main/java/demo