# Any performance improvement in Spring Batch compared to Java 8 parallel stream for huge data processing

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, java-8, spring-batch

I'm going to load `8 million records from an` elastic`search index and then do processing and save it to a`Postgres database`.

I thought of doing it in the following ways.

- Method 1. Load 1000 records from elastic and keep a list of
  objects and persist it into `Postgres` using `java 8` parallel stream.
- Method 2. Using Spring Batch loading 1000 records as chunk and
  persisting into `Postgres`

Here performance is more important for me. In less time I would like to insert all records.
Are there any performance improvements in `spring batch` compared to `java 8` parallel streams?

Please let me know the best way to achieve this kind of scenario in a faster way.

Comment: If it is one time loading activity I would go for Stream as 8M is not a huge number. And if it is an ongoing activity after this initial load, I would go for spring batch configured to use its schedule and monitoring etc features.

Comment: @AjayKumar, i have one more doubt, mostly i see example in various site, they used spring batch for flat files like csv etc. whether can we take data from database and process further in spring batch ?

Comment: Of course you can.!. And if you need help on that, Google SE is flooded with working examples to get you started.

Comment: @AjayKumar, for first comment- even in spring boot with java 8 stream, we can do scheduler using quartz right. is there any significance performance using spring batch ?

Comment: Spring batch gives you all the features And flexibility you can expect from a batch service. Just configure it, and let it do the hard work for you. But if you are not comfortable and dont have time to learn and adapt it and as I said earlier, if it is one time activity, go for Stream option which you are already comfortable with. Good Luck.!

Comment: @AjayKumar, thanks for your help

Comment: Sure thing. This might interest you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509821/how-to-read-data-from-one-db-table-and-write-data-to-another-table-using-spring

Comment: I guess an important part of your question is : what "processing" do you have to do ? If it's just mapping from object A to object B, it sure won't be the same answer as if it's aggregating on some key and computing partial data and ordering by some other, etc...

Answer (score 3):

> Here performance is more important for me

If you use a Java 8 parallel stream you are limited to a single machine. However, if you use Spring Batch, you can run your job on multiple machines using remote partitioning. That's a big difference since performance is your priority.

For this kind of jobs which might take hours, fault-tolerance and restartability are key concerns IMO. If you use Spring Batch, you can get these features for free while you need to implement them yourself if you use a raw Java 8 parallel stream.